# SAS: prof freq list view, creating dummy

Tags: variables, sas, frequency, proc

is there any way to create dummy variables for the list view generated from SAS: proc freq?
e.g.

this is my proc freq output :

x   y   z   N   %

0   0   0   10  2.8

0   0   1   20  5.6

0   1   0   30  8.3

0   1   1   40  11.1

1   0   0   50  13.9

1   0   1   60  16.7

1   1   0   70  19.4

1   1   1   80  22.2

can I create (easily in proc freq) dummy variables that can have 1/0 values for each level of the output (that is, 8 dummy variables) OR alternatively, a single variable which will have incremental value of 1,2,3,... for each level of output???

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it with a single variable, assuming you just have combinations of variables with values of only 0 or 1:

```
data yourdata;
    do i = 1 to 100;
        x = round(ranuni(1));
        y = round(ranuni(2));
        z = round(ranuni(3));
        t = 1;
        output;
    end;
run;

proc summary nway data = yourdata;
  class x y z;
    var t;
  output out = summary_ds n=;
run;

data summary_ds;
    set summary_ds;
    singlevar = input(cats(x,y,z),binary3.);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. that's actually a brilliant solution.